# PHP JavaScript Countdown Timer

Tags: php, javascript, countdown

I need to make a countdown timer that displays a specific number of minutes and seconds counting down - not a countdown to a certain date.

And depending on a variable, change these numbers.

So for `$video == 1`, I need to display on the page: `8 minutes & 54 seconds` (counting down)

And for `$video == 2`, I need to display on the page: `5 minutes & 01 seconds` (counting down)

I also need the countdown display to disappear after the time has elapsed, but maybe I should put that into a different question.

The problem I'm having is the all the countdown scripts I can find deal with counting down to a specific date.

Comment: do you have code of what you are trying?

Comment: I've having a really hard time with this and not understanding any of the responses I'm getting.

Maybe I can simply it for everyone... Is there a way for me to display in-line a minute and seconds countdown timer?

It can be JS or PHP, as long as I can set the minutes and seconds right inside the code block.

Then I can repeat it inside if statements for the $video variable. I know this is not the best way to do it, but nothing is making sense to me.

Comment: So, if someone could give me a self-contained (no libraries, no external scripts, etc) block of code that will display X min & Y sec (counting down), that would be awesome!

Comment: I'm abandoning this. It's out of my league. Thank you all for trying to help me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need, just enter the total time in seconds in the `<span>` tags. `30` and `120` here for demo. Should work if you copy and paste directly into a webpage. Add and edit code as needed.

```
<span id="countdown-1">30 seconds</span>
<span id="countdown-2">120 seconds</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize clock countdowns by using the total seconds in the elements tag
    secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-1').innerHTML,10);
    setTimeout("countdown('countdown-1',"+secs+")", 1000);
    secs       = parseInt(document.getElementById('countdown-2').innerHTML,10);
    setTimeout("countdown('countdown-2',"+secs+")", 1000);

    /**
     * Countdown function
     * Clock count downs to 0:00 then hides the element holding the clock
     * @param id Element ID of clock placeholder
     * @param timer Total seconds to display clock
     */
    function countdown(id, timer){
        timer--;
        minRemain  = Math.floor(timer / 60);
        secsRemain = new String(timer - (minRemain * 60));
        // Pad the string with leading 0 if less than 2 chars long
        if (secsRemain.length < 2) {
            secsRemain = '0' + secsRemain;
        }

        // String format the remaining time
        clock      = minRemain + ":" + secsRemain;
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock;
        if ( timer > 0 ) {
            // Time still remains, call this function again in 1 sec
            setTimeout("countdown('" + id + "'," + timer + ")", 1000);
        } else {
            // Time is out! Hide the countdown
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php 
 $countDownTime = 0;
 if ($video == 1) $countDownTime = (8*60 + 54);
 else if ($video == 2) $countDownTime = (5*60 + 1);
 echo '<script>var countdownTime="' . $countDownTime . '";</script>"'; 
 ?>

 <script>
 <!-- as per the hyper linked reference below -->
 $(selector).countdown({until: countdownTime});
 </script>
```

Using the following library, you can implement a JQuery timer using the var `countdownTime` you specify above...

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html <-- tutorial on the first page!

**Edit** Replaced $someTimeInSeconds with $countDownTime

Comment: I don't really understand how to use the library and I don't understand where the variable $someTimeinSeconds gets set.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var x, secs = 600; //declared globally

x = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

function myFunc()
{
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =  secs; //assuming there is a label with id 'timer'
    secs --;
    if(secs == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('timer').style.hidden = true;
        clearInterval(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Is this JavaScript? Where are the variables for different videos? And how do I the countdown to display on the page?

Comment: @Dustin Yes, it is javascript. My code counts down 600 seconds (5 minutes). If you are wondering how, I'd suggest you lookup setInterval as I do not want to rob you of the learning experience. Adjusting the countdown time depending on $video must be trival from here.

Comment: I don't see how this displays on the page. And does it do minutes and seconds? Or just minutes?

Comment: @Dustin if there is a label defined in HTML like `<label id='timer'>timer not started</label>`, `document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =  secs;` would replace "timer not started" with number of seconds. If you want to display it as minutes and seconds, it is only a matter of simple math to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is a countdown script located at http://javascript.internet.com/time-date/countdown-timer.html that doesn't countdown to a date but rather a specified amount of minutes.

The code may be customized as follows to get the desired effect

```
<?php
 if ($video===1){
    $time="8:54";
 }
 if ($video===2){
    $time="5:01";
 }


?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="countDown.js"></script>

    <form name="cd">
    <input id="txt" readonly="true" type="text" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" border="0" name="disp">
    </form>
```

Make sure that the contents of countDown.js looks like this:

```
/* This script and many more are available free online at
The JavaScript Source :: http://javascript.internet.com
Created by: Neill Broderick :: http://www.bespoke-software-solutions.co.uk/downloads/downjs.php */

var mins
var secs;

function cd() {
    mins = 1 * m("10"); // change minutes here
    secs = 0 + s(":01"); // change seconds here (always add an additional second to your total)
    redo();
}

function m(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
        break;
    }
    return(obj.substring(0, i));
}

function s(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
        break;
    }
    return(obj.substring(i + 1, obj.length));
}

function dis(mins,secs) {
    var disp;
    if(mins <= 9) {
        disp = " 0";
    } else {
        disp = " ";
    }
    disp += mins + ":";
    if(secs <= 9) {
        disp += "0" + secs;
    } else {
        disp += secs;
    }
    return(disp);
}

function redo() {
    secs--;
    if(secs == -1) {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
    }
    document.cd.disp.value = dis(mins,secs); // setup additional displays here.
    if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
        window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to continue."); // change timeout message as required
        // window.location = "yourpage.htm" // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
    } else {
        cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
    }
}

function init() {
  cd();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: This show 8:54, but it doesn't count down. Then it changes to 10:00 and it doesn't count down.

Comment: You might have copied the wrong information into countDown.js, I've edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm looking at doing something similar. Currently I have a simple countdown timer that is based off of current time that counts down every 30min. The problem is that I have to use a meta refresh to update it. I'm wondering if a combination of javascript and PHP might be a simpler solution to this answer. Use javascript to call the php code and automatically update it? Maybe set a variable for the time in the php script to be called with javascript? Well, here's the code I have that might help. I'm still learning.

```
$minutes_left = ($minutes)?((30 - $minutes)-(($seconds)?1:0)):0;
$minutes_left = str_pad ($minutes_left , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$seconds_left = ($seconds)?(60 - $seconds):0;
$seconds_left = str_pad ($seconds_left , 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo '<center><h1 style="font-color:white;">Next station break in: '.$minutes_left.'m '.$seconds_left.'s</h2></center>';

?>
```

I just have to figure out how to get it to reset itself at the end of every 30min and to update without meta refresh.